# What are the technique of loading images for slideshow?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a web application something like image gallery for the user with carousel at the bottom of the application. I was thinking of 
a scenario for example what if the user uploaded 1000 images on the application image gallery.
 I was just wandering what is the proper way or technique to load 1000 images that is fast so that the user can view it immediately.
 Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1000 images is *a lot*. I would definitely not load them all at once, but rather in batches somehow. Kind of like Facebook does (I think). It fills up the view, and when you scroll down it keeps loading more, but only as you scroll down. Could also simplify it by using a "Load more"-button.

If it really is a carousel as you say, I would expect it to only show a certain number of images. In that case I would just load the ones visible and for example twice that in a buffer. Then when the user goes to the next page you can replace the current ones with the first ones in the buffer and load some more into the buffer.

Comment: The first version of my application is is using jQuery Cycle for images and carouFredSel plugin carousel thumbnails. What i was thinking is about to load 10 images first then use a javascript function to gets the remaining images simultaneously and append to the ul of the carousel thumbnails but having problem for appending the new element. Im thinking of some solution but it looks like my options becomes limited. By the way im getting the data from the API.

Comment: Maybe you can find some help at http://samples.geekality.net/image-fetcher. There I use an AJAX call to get a JSON array with lots of image URLs. I then create img tags for all of them, adding them to the page.

Answer (score 0):

Loading 1000 images at one time would be a ridiculous waste of bandwidth, not to mention it would cause major lag for the client. Some client-side JavaScript/jQuery would be required rather than PHP to load the images dynamically as the user scrolls through them, so no more resources/images are requested than needed at the specific time, say 10 at a time. Using the `.click()` event in jQuery on an element and checking for the end of the 'carousel' so to speak, and then using something like `$("#element").attr("src", "imagePath.jpg");` to swap the images shown on the carousel should work.